# How to concatenate .pdf files with VBA?

Tags: vba, pdf

I am trying to concatenate .pdf files with VBA.  Nothing fancy, literally sticking the pages one after each other.  I did numerous web searches but was unable to find any solutions that are even close to working.  Has anyone done this before?  Thanks!

Comment: by the way, are you trying to put one page *after* the other or one page *on top of* the other?

Comment: @yms: [concatenate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/concatenate), [superpose](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/concatenate)

Comment: @jean he also said "sticking the pages on top of each other", that is why I asked for clarification.Also, as a developer of pdf-related products, I have seen all those terms being used for any scenario without distinction

Comment: sorry, I mean "one after the other".  I edited the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a GPL library is a valid option for you, you could use ghostscript as proposed [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102090/combining-pdf-files-with-ghostscript-how-to-include-original-file-names). You can do this by calling the [ShellExecute](http://www.xcelfiles.com/ShellExecuteA.html) function from Windows API or by using the class `WScript.Shell` if you are creating a vbscript file.

If a commercial library is an option, I recommend [Amyuni PDF Creator ActiveX](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreatoractivex) or [Amyuni PDF Converter](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfconverter), both have an `Append` function that will do the work. The code for Amyuni PDF Converter for example would look like this:

```
Set PDFDoc = CreateObject("CDintfEx.Document.4.5")
PDFdoc.SetLicenseKey "your company", "your license code"
PDFDoc.Open "test_append1.pdf"
PDFDoc.Append "test_append2.pdf"
PDFDoc.Save "result_append.pdf"
Set PDFdoc = Nothing
```

*Usual disclaimer applies for the latest suggestion*

Answer (score 1):

I found this topic while having the same task, with a customer using amyuni. Thanks to yms for a good approach. I found Acces crashing on "Set PDFdoc = Nothing". This one works fine for me:

```
Public Sub fctPDO_Concatenate_pdf_with_Amyuni_Document_6_0()

' PDO: Usage of .append: Crashes on destruction of pdfdoc-Object. pdf-file is created properly. But usind .append , MS Access crashes - without it's okay.

'       Solution: Build second pdfdoc2 - object , and concatenate using  .AppendEx(Object)   .


On Error Resume Next
Dim PDFdoc As Object
Dim PDFdoc2 As Object

Const strLibraryVersion As String = "CDintfEx.Document.6.0"
' PDO: Examples
'Set PDFdoc = CreateObject("CDintfEx.Document.6.0")     ' PDO: See Object catalog
'Set PDFdoc = CreateObject("CDintfEx.Document")         ' PDO: Not sufficient w/o version
'Set PDFdoc = CreateObject("CDintfEx.Document.4.5")     ' PDO: Older version

Set PDFdoc = CreateObject(strLibraryVersion)
Set PDFdoc2 = CreateObject(strLibraryVersion)

'PDO: Open first file
PDFdoc.Open "D:\PDO_test\Beratungsprotokoll_2018.pdf"


'PDFdoc.Append "D:\PDO_test\GV_0093Z0_Einzelantrag.pdf"   ' PDO: Crashes on   set PDFdoc = nothing

' PDO: Open and append second file (as Object, not as file)
PDFdoc2.Open "D:\PDO_test\GV_0093Z0_Einzelantrag.pdf"
PDFdoc.AppendEx PDFdoc2

' PDO: Open and append third file (as Object, not as file). Re-use of second Object possible
PDFdoc2.Open "D:\PDO_test\result_append_sammel.pdf"
PDFdoc.AppendEx PDFdoc2


'PDO: Save with a new name
PDFdoc.Save "D:\PDO_test\result_append_sammelsammel.pdf"

'PDFdoc.Close => Not existing.

Set PDFdoc = Nothing  '=> Access crashed, with PDFdoc.Append 
Set PDFdoc2 = Nothing

Debug.Print "Done: " & Now() & " Error: " & Err.Number

End Sub
```

If you prefer Ghostscript you can use a single line:

```
C:\PROGRA~2\gs\gs9.19\bin\gswin32c.exe -q -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOwnerPassword=pass2 -sUserPassword=pass1 -dCompatibilityLevel=2.0 -sOutputFile="D:\PDO_test\Beratungsprotokoll_2018_Sammel.pdf" "D:\PDO_test\Beratungsprotokoll_2018.pdf" "D:\PDO_test\GV_0093Z0_Einzelantrag.pdf"
```

This concatenates the two latter files into the (new) first one and applies a password (see security details before applying). The short path can be obtained with a FileScripting Object "fso" using

```
fso.GetFolder(strFolder).ShortPath
```

Answer (score 0):

I run sedja-console and add my pdf's as parameters. Quite easy to implement. Do not forget to check before starting Sedja-console if the readonly flag of the possible previous created destination pdf isn't set to yes, as there is no feedback of this external process.